# Fraction based quantization of a value

Tags: python, quantization

I'm developing a basic Python 2.7 musical sequencer.

> A small background for people not used to musical terms.
>   A sequencer is a program that can "ask" some other program or
>   device to "play" events at specific times, somehow similar to the
>   "piano rolls" of an old [Player piano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Player_piano).
>   One thing that a software sequencer always makes available to the
>   user is the "quantization", which is the ability to "move" events
>   (usually notes that have been input via GUI or through an external
>   instrument) to specific timings, and then obtain a more precise
>   sound reproduction based on the current *tempo*.
>   Musical timings are based on simple 2 or 3 multiples fractions, so
>   you can have a note that starts or has a length of a quater, 3 
>   eights, a third and so on.

What I need is a **fast** function that is able to *quantize* "inaccurate" values.
For example, if the quantization is set to quarters and a note has a timing of 2.6, its value will become 2.5. If the quantization is based on eights, the value will be 2.625.

So far, the fastest function I was able to find was this one:

```python
def quantize(value, numerator, denominator):
    #use the least common multiple, so I can get a
    #reference integer to round to.
    temp = round(value * numerator * denominator, 0)
    #return the re-normalized value
    return temp * numerator / float(denominator)
```

I've been looking into the Python `decimal` module and its `quantize()` method, but I wasn't able to understand if it can actually do what I need.

Is there a faster and, maybe, builtin function/method in the standard library that I could use instead?

Please note that I'm not interested in the round method differences whenever the last reference float is 5, as it doesn't need to be "programmatically" precise by concept.

Also, to all the musicians reading this: the actual reference will be "beats" (as in quarter notes for common time based music), so I will obviously multiply the `temp` value by 4 before rounding and then divide the value again before returning, but that's not the point here :-)

Comment: Decimal will do what you want, but my implementation with that is nearly 3x slower than what you've already got:  from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_FLOOR
def quantize2(number, numerator, denominator):
    number, ratio = Decimal(number), Decimal(numerator/denominator)
    return (number / ratio).quantize(Decimal(1), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR) * ratio

Comment: @sh37211 That's neat. However, I think you need `ROUND_CEILING` (instead of `ROUND_FLOOR`) to reproduce the results of the OP's `quantize` function.

Comment: @tel  No. "if the quantization is set to quarters and a note has a timing of 2.6, its value will become 2.5."  ROUND_CEILING will result in 2.75.   ROUND_FLOOR correctly gives 2.5.

Comment: @sh37211 Sure, but what about eighth notes? If you use `ROUND_FLOOR`, then for eighth notes `quantize2(2.6, 1, 8)` will give `2.5` instead of the desired `2.625` (which was the example I was working off of when I wrote the previous comment).

Comment: Ok, it seems that using ROUND_CEILING I actually get the wanted result (I had to do a float() of the denominator since I'm stuck with Python 2). Anyway, while it seems to work as expected, I'm afraid it's still too slow. Thank you both, anyway.

Comment: I updated my answer to be Python 2.7 compatible (you just need `from __future__ import division`). There's also now 3 different versions of my quantization function that each give a different rounding behavior. If you want to round up (which is what `ROUND_CEILING ` does), use `quantizeCeil`.

Comment: Thank you @tel, I only saw your comment and edit a while ago. Maybe I'll put that method in a separate file and then import it.

Answer (score 3):

## Fast solutions

All of these solutions are significantly faster than the OP's `quantize` function (see [this old thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3950372/425458) for a discussion of the reasons why). Take your pick depending on your desired rounding behavior.

### Round to nearest

This exactly reproduces the behavior of the OP's `quantize` function:

```
from __future__ import division

def quantizeRound(value, numerator, denominator):
    ratio = (numerator/denominator)
    return (value + ratio/2) // ratio * ratio
```

### Round up

```
from __future__ import division

def quantizeCeil(value, numerator, denominator):
    ratio = (numerator/denominator)
    return (value // ratio + 1) * ratio
```

### Round down

```
from __future__ import division

def quantizeFloor(value, numerator, denominator):
    ratio = (numerator/denominator)
    return value // ratio * ratio
```

## Testing

I compared the output of the OP's `quantize` and my `quantizeRound` (in both Python 2.7 and 3.6) over a wide range of possible inputs, and ensured that they matched:

```
for denom in (2,4,8):
    for v in np.linspace(0,5,51):
        assert quantize(v, 1, denom) == quantizeRound(v, 1, denom)
```

## Timings

```
%%timeit
quantize(2.6, 1, 8)
833 ns ± 11.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
quantizeRound(2.6, 1, 8)
296 ns ± 2.93 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
quantizeCeil(2.6, 1, 8)
277 ns ± 3.49 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

%%timeit
quantizeFloor(2.6, 1, 8)
241 ns ± 3.61 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

## Python 2/3 compatibility

The line `from __future__ import division` ensures that, whether you run the code in Python 2 or 3, in either case `/` will perform `float` division. You may not want to use `from __future__ import division` in your code (since it will change the behavior of all code in the module in which it's imported). In that case, you can either place the quantization function in its own separate module, or you can use this alternative Python 2/3 compatible version of `quantizeRound`:

```
# alternative Python 2/3 compatible version 
def quantizeRound(value, numerator, denominator):
    ratio = (float(numerator)/denominator)
    return (value + ratio/2.0) // ratio * ratio
```

However, it is a bit slower than the version that uses `from __future__ ...`:

```
%%timeit
# alternative Python 2/3 compatible version
quantizeRound(2.6, 1, 8)
441 ns ± 9.91 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

## Speeding up batch quantization of many notes at a time

If you have large batches of notes to quantize, you can speed up the process by using Numpy arrays. The form of `quantizeRound` (and my other quantization functions) is compatible with using arrays as inputs. Given an array of notes, `quantizeRound` will quantize them all using a single vectorized calculation. For example:

```
notes = np.arange(10) + .6
print(quantizeRound(notes, 1, 8))
```

Output:

```
[0.625 1.625 2.625 3.625 4.625 5.625 6.625 7.625 8.625 9.625]
```

## Timings

The vectorized array-based approach is almost twice as fast as the equivalent `for` loop:

```
%%timeit
for n in notes:
    quantizeRound(n, 1, 8)
5.63 µs ± 40.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

%%timeit
quantizeRound(notes, 1, 8)
2.93 µs ± 20.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: That's really interesting, and I will probably mark this as the accepted answer after some further testing, while I'm still curious about "why" it's actually faster than my original implementation. Nice hint about using Numpy arrays (I already use it for other meanings), but unfortunally I doubt I'll be able to use it like that, as some events are related to others: the computed representation of notes implies that each note actually has both a "note on" and a "note off" event, and "straight" quantization could create 0-length notes, leading to sequencing issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't good old integer arithmetic all you need?

```
def quantize(value, numerator, denominator):
    #use the least common multiple, so I can get a
    #reference integer to round to.
    temp = round(value * numerator * denominator, 0)
    #return the re-normalized value
    return temp * numerator / float(denominator)

from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_FLOOR
def quantize2(number, numerator, denominator):
    number, ratio = Decimal(number), Decimal(numerator/denominator)
    return (number / ratio).quantize(Decimal(1), rounding=ROUND_FLOOR) * ratio


def quantize3(number, numerator, denominator):
    ratio = numerator/denominator
    return (number // ratio) * ratio


def testfunc():
    return quantize(2.6,1,4)

def testfunc2():
    return quantize2(2.6,1,4)

def testfunc3():
    return quantize3(2.6,1,4)

$ python -mtimeit -s'import quantize' 'quantize.testfunc()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.11 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'import quantize' 'quantize.testfunc2()'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.3 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'import quantize' 'quantize.testfunc3()'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.421 usec per loop

>>> print quantize3(2.6,1,4)

2.5
```